# CoreData sort results by number of matching relationships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I'm not able to figure out how to sort results from CoreData based on the number of matching relationships.

Concrete situation:

I have Recipe(s) that have one or more RecipeIngredient(s). I have a search interface where I can select multiple Ingredient(s) and want to get back Recipe(s) ordered by how many RecipeIngredient(s) match my selection. Basically I want to find the recipes with the highest number of matching ingredients.

CoreData schema:

[image]

Here is what I've done until now, (sort descriptor is just a default until I figure out how to handle this):

```
    func searchRecipes(
        searchRequest: RecipeSearchRequest
    ) -> [CDRecipe] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDRecipe> = CDRecipe.fetchRequest()
        var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
        if searchRequest.searchString != "" {
            predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", searchRequest.searchString.lowercased()))
        }
        if searchRequest.savedOnly {
            predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "saved == %@", "true"))
        }

// HERE
        if !searchRequest.includedIngredientIDs.isEmpty {
            predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "ANY ingredients.ingredient.identifier IN %@", searchRequest.includedIngredientIDs))
        }
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: predicates)
        
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CDRecipe.title, ascending: true)
        
        
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = searchRequest.limit
        do {
            let recipes = try coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return recipes
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
    }
```

I have also considered pulling all the recipes in my database and doing this sorting in memory. However I have 10K+ recipes and will have more in the future so doing this will would be highly inefficient.

Comment: Does your search predicate successfully return only the recipes that match your ingredients?  If so you are probably dealing with much less than 10,000 recipes.  Sorting the results in memory is probably the simplest way

Comment: It does, and yes the final result set is much smaller than the 10k. I'm still hoping that CoreData has this use case covered and I simply couldn't find it yet.

Comment: There is no predicate in core data that can sort your results because there is no property that represents the count of the number of matches for your `in`.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Paulw11! Then will do try out in memory sorting. If that doesn't work well will probably switch to plain Sqlite